# Most efficient phase linear x4 resampling algorithm

Tags: fft, fourier, resampling

I'm working on a program in which I need to do the following about 20 times for each block of audio:
- Upsample from 192 to 768 kHz (x4)
- Clip
- Downsample back to 192 kHz (/4)

What I'm using now:

- FFT block size 4096
- Add 0's at the end of the FFT block
- IFFT block size 16384
- Clip audio
- FFT block size 16384
- IFFT block size 4096 (this ignores the higher freqs so it automatically lowpass filters)

For the FFT's I'm using Intel's IPP library, and all the other code (adding 0's, clipping) is written using AVX intrinsics.

Still, doing this 20 times is heavy, and I know that it is possible to do it more efficiently, because in the 1st FFT step I'm adding 0's which are then used in the calculations (while they could be discarded) and at the other end, 75% of the FFT values that are calculated are discarded as well. So, even with FFT's, this should be possible more efficiently, which leads me to think that there must be more efficient resampling algorithms out there. But I haven't been able to find one yet.

Comment: I have to admit that I am baffled about what you are accomplishing by clipping at the higher rate, then going back to your original sample rate.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Clip with 4x oversampling to also remove peaks between samples.

Comment: I suggest you clarify your description: is there a low pass filter in your upsampler? What exactly does the clipper do? Is the signal low pass filtered before downsampling?

Comment: No lowpass filtering before upsampling. Downsampling in the way I described automatically ignores the higher freqs so it basically automatically lowpass-filters.

Comment: What kind of clipping do you use, hard or soft?

Comment: @fibonatic: Hard clipping.